# How can I auto-post updates to my Page's stream on Google Plus?

Tags: jenkins, stream, google-plus

So, I've written some code to analyze a commit from my SVN repository and I have Jenkins running it.  I'd like to figure out a way to have Jenkins post to my Google Plus stream.  For reference, you can view the last couple of posts here: https://plus.google.com/+Casual-dev/posts

I am running into the issue where I cannot login without a real person behind the console and it's a headless server.  I'd like to just write a java app and have it either login and share to Google Plus directly or send an email somewhere that will be posted to Google Plus.
Does anyone have an example of a headless login/post or a non-SMS based method of posting to Google Plus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at HootSuite's API, which should allow you do what you want. The Google+ write API is only available to a limited number of providers, and HootSuite is one of them.